# jQuery changing base64 URL when storing it as a variable?

Tags: jquery, base64

For some reason when I pass a base64 url through jquery it is changing the value of
canvas.toDataURL();

```
window.open(canvas.toDataURL());
```

will produce it correctly

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAzCAYAAACuR5nYAAAATklEQVRIS2P8DwQMRADGoaDw6dOnxHlmy5YtxClsbm4mTmFgYCBxChUUFIhTCIyUUYU4UybjaPDgy7WjwYO3TBsNntHgwQiB0USBN1EAAJ80SZkuW4e0AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

however

```
var url = canvas.toDataURL();
window.open(url);
```

will change it to

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAzCAYAAACuR5nYAAAALElEQVRIS2NkIBIwEqmOYVQh3pAaDZ7R4MEIgdFEMZooRhMFOARGs8JgzQoA3IkANLlv8A4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

This obviously corrupts the url,
Why is jQuery messing with my URL, is their a workaround?

Thank you for any help.

```
<canvas id="colors" height="50" width="10"></canvas>
<div class="colors">
<input type="text" class="url" value="0" />
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="text" class="pos" value="0" />
        <input type="text" class="color" value="#ffffff" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="text" class="pos" value="1" />
        <input type="text" class="color" value="#000000" />
    </div>
</div>

$('.colors').each(function(){
    $(this).on('colors', function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('colors');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var lingrad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,50);

        $('.inputs').each(function(){
             var pos = $(this).find('.pos').val();
             var color = $(this).find('.color').val();
                 lingrad.addColorStop(pos, color);
        });

        ctx.fillStyle = lingrad;
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,10,50);

        var url = canvas.toDataURL();
        $(this).find('.url').val(url);
        alert(url);
    window.open(url);
    });
});

$('input').on('change', function(){
    $(this).trigger('colors');
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with jQuery? You question makes absolutely no sense to me. Can you please give more information?

Comment: I want to handle variable in jQuery to update the value of an input so I can grab it with php, the url changes dynamically. Whether I try to store it in a variable or change the input using .val() it will corrupt the url

Comment: So why don't you show the essential parts of your code??

Comment: Didn't think I need to, just wrote an example

Comment: I feel like such a god damn idiot but after writing that example I saw my mistake. I was telling it to update the input BEFORE the freaking .each(); so it was sending an incomplete base64 URL, such a noob mistake I'll go whip myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: The data-type argument is optional, so I doubt this will fix OP's problem.